# got TypeError: when run some js codes

Tags: javascript

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Mouse Capture</TITLE>
<SCRIPT>
// Get the element, add a click listener...
document.getElementById("parent-list").addEventListener("click",function(e) {
    // e.target is the clicked element!
    // If it was a list item
    if(e.target && e.target.nodeName == "LI") {
        // List item found!  Output the ID!
        console.log("List item ",e.target.id.replace("post-")," was clicked!");
    }
});
</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<ul id="parent-list">
    <li id="post-1">Item 1</li>
    <li id="post-2">Item 2</li>
    <li id="post-3">Item 3</li>
    <li id="post-4">Item 4</li>
    <li id="post-5">Item 5</li>
    <li id="post-6">Item 6</li>
</ul>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Above code is from here: http://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate

Question:

I tried above codes in Chrome and Firework, both do no work, in firefox->console, it shows: `TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null`, so what is the problem?

Comment: Script is at the top, and the element is down below. Things load in order in the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because when the script is executed the dom element is loaded. Move the script to the bottom of the page to fix the problem or execute the script on document ready

Ex:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Mouse Capture</TITLE>
<SCRIPT>
window.onload = function(){
    // Get the element, add a click listener...
    document.getElementById("parent-list").addEventListener("click",function(e) {
        // e.target is the clicked element!
        // If it was a list item
        if(e.target && e.target.nodeName == "LI") {
            // List item found!  Output the ID!
            console.log("List item ",e.target.id.replace("post-")," was clicked!");
        }
    });
}
</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<ul id="parent-list">
    <li id="post-1">Item 1</li>
    <li id="post-2">Item 2</li>
    <li id="post-3">Item 3</li>
    <li id="post-4">Item 4</li>
    <li id="post-5">Item 5</li>
    <li id="post-6">Item 6</li>
</ul>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 1):

When `document.getElementById("parent-list")` executes there is no element with id parent-list as it executes before the elment becomes available. you can solve it by moving your js code:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Mouse Capture</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<ul id="parent-list">
    <li id="post-1">Item 1</li>
    <li id="post-2">Item 2</li>
    <li id="post-3">Item 3</li>
    <li id="post-4">Item 4</li>
    <li id="post-5">Item 5</li>
    <li id="post-6">Item 6</li>
</ul>
<SCRIPT>
// Get the element, add a click listener...
document.getElementById("parent-list").addEventListener("click",function(e) {
    // e.target is the clicked element!
    // If it was a list item
    if(e.target && e.target.nodeName == "LI") {
        // List item found!  Output the ID!
        console.log("List item ",e.target.id.replace("post-")," was clicked!");
    }
});
</SCRIPT>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```